# Show Uploaded File Django: Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, static, django-templates, media

How to display the uploaded `ProductPhoto` images in a django template in Django 1.8.4?

For the following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def photos(self):
        return ProductPhoto.objects.all()

class ProductPhoto(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/product/', null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='photos')
```

With these settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And these urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'myApp.views.index', name='index'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

---

How do I display the uploaded `ProductPhoto` objects in this template:

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    <div id="some-div">
        {% for photo in product.photos.all %}
        <div class="item"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ photo }}"/></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I thought I was on the right track with: `{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ photo }}` but this is incorrect. I also have tried `{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ photo.url }}` but neither is displaying anything on the template. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, delete the photos() method on your photo models as it can be misunderstood with the related_name on your ProductPhoto objects.

Then, just do the following:

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    <div id="some-div">
        {% for product_photo in product.photos.all %}
        <div class="item"><img src="{{ product_photo.photo.url }}"/></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

Here are things you need to change:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    # this is wrong, get rid of it:
    #def photos(self):
    #    return ProductPhoto.objects.all()

class ProductPhoto(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/product/', null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='photos')
```

You don't need MEDIA_URL there, django dev server knows what to do with it, (while in production you need to configure apache, nginx etc. to serve those):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'myApp.views.index', name='index'),
] # + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Just like this:

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    <div id="some-div">
        {% for product_photo in product.photos.all %}
            <div class="item"><img src="{{ product_photo.photo.url }}"/></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```